# LDD cannot find library on sol11_64 bit

Tags: solaris, solaris-10, gcc, solaris-11, library

We have been compiling with gcc successfully on Solaris 10. Now we are porting to 64-bit on Solaris 11 (sol11_64). We use a library developed in house called MSP and use -wl,rpath (equivalent to -R... also tried with -R) during compile to specify the run-time library locations. On sol10, the output of LDD shows 2 of 2 MSP libraries found. On sol11_64, there's now 3 libraries shown in the LDD output, with the new one not being able to be found, even though it is in the same location as one of the others. If I add that location to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH, then LDD picks it up. We do NOT wish to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH as a permanent solution.

sol10 LDD output:

```
    libmsp.so =>     /opt/msp/lib/fiorano/libmsp.so
    libfmq-crtl.so =>        /opt/msp/lib/fiorano/vendor-files/lib/libfmq-crtl.so
```

sol11_64 LDD output:

```
    libmsp.so =>     /opt/msp/lib/fiorano/libmsp.so
    libfmq-crtl.so =>        /opt/msp/lib/fiorano/vendor-files/lib/libfmq-crtl.so
    libfmq-crtl-ssl.so =>    (file not found)
```

sol11_64 LDD output with path in LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
    libmsp.so =>     /opt/msp/lib/fiorano/libmsp.so
    libfmq-crtl.so =>        /opt/msp/lib/fiorano/vendor-files/lib/libfmq-crtl.so
    libfmq-crtl-ssl.so =>    /opt/msp/lib/fiorano/vendor-files/lib/libfmq-crtl-ssl.so
```

I did check permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root     root        2.0M Dec 18 17:49 libfmq-crtl-ssl.so*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root     root        2.0M Dec 18 17:49 libfmq-crtl.so*
```

Comment: You're aware you have answered your own question? Just add the new dynamic library folder path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH during initialization of the server.

Comment: ok, it seems it's not the solaris way, here: "If you need to bake a specific runpath into your library or executable, then you should use the -R flag to the linker. If building with gcc, then use -Wl,Rpath (I think)." (from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21542094/2172543)

Comment: I've edited the question to include that we have also tried -wl,rpath and also do not wish to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH as a permanent workaround. We would prefer to know why this is occurring and how to fix it.

Comment: Have you not added your library path with `crle`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this library was a new dependency on sol11_64 all of a sudden, I needed to add it elsewhere in our makefile, specifically our LIBS variable, which is passed in during linking along with the runtime library paths. I think this part tells it what libraries to actually look for.

Before:

```
LIBS := -lpthread -lmsp -lfmq-crtl -lxml2
```

After:

```
LIBS := -lpthread -lmsp -lfmq-crtl -lfmq-crtl-ssl -lxml2
```

makefile target:

```
$(EXE): $(MACHOBJ) $(MACH)/main.o
    cd $(MACH); $(CC) -o ../$@ $(OBJ) main.o \
    ../../lib/$(MACH)/libmain.a \
    -L/opt/msp/lib/fiorano \
    -L/opt/msp/lib/fiorano/vendor-files/lib \
    -R/opt/msp/lib/fiorano \
    -R/opt/msp/lib/fiorano/vendor-files/lib \
    $(MACHLFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(MACHLLIBS)
```